# Why are pregnant women are prohibited from performing house warming in their 7th month?

Tags: rituals, women, pregnancy

Why is it that pregnant women are prohibited from performing housewarming rituals during their 7th month of pregnancy? I’ve heard they are not supposed to listen to the mantras. Can someone please explain the reasoning for this?

Comment: Women of all castes ate generally prohibited from hearing Vaidika mantras, because they are considered on par with sudras due to lack of yajnopavita. And the 7th month of pregnancy is dedicated to simantonnayana samsara. As far as it is known, there isn't any awareness from this side about women in their 7th month of pregnancy being forbidden from performing grhapravesha.

Comment: there may be some purana that says this, but it not a assertion of the vedas. The vedas deal with brahman and how to attain brahman, not popular customs.

Comment: I think OP means "baby shower" or Seemantam ceremony.  grihapravesham or housewarming is performed by the man of the house.